# NestJS provider classes overwriting each-other in different event loops

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am having an issue where my common library injectables are being overwritten by eachother

bootstrap file runs this file along with a proxy server to initialise local microservices

```js
import { serviceA } from '@company/serviceA'
import { serviceB } from '@company/serviceB'
import { serviceC } from '@company/serviceC'
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads'
import path from 'path'

enum Services {
  serviceA = 'serviceA',
  serviceB = 'serviceB',
  serviceC = 'serviceC'
}

interface WorkerData {
  service: Services
}
export class ServiceStarter {
  private readonly filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'bootstrap.js')
  constructor(private readonly isMainThread: boolean, private readonly workerData: WorkerData) { }

  async startAllServices(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      if (this.isMainThread) {
        new Worker(this.filePath, { workerData: { service: Services.serviceA } });
        new Worker(this.filePath, { workerData: { service: Services.serviceB } });
        new Worker(this.filePath, { workerData: { service: Services.serviceC } });
      } else {
        await this.childService(this.workerData)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
    }

  }

  async childService({ service }: WorkerData) {
    console.log(`Starting Service - ${service}`)
    switch (service) {
      case Services.serviceA:
        return await serviceB()
      case Services.serviceB:
        return await serviceA()
      case Services.serviceC:
        return await serviceC()
      default:
        throw new Error('Service Unavailable');
    }
  }
}
```

There is a common folder that contains a ton of injectables in the constructor and different classes have their implementations inside the different services declared in the .module folder

Implementation 1

```js
@Module({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [
    ...commonProviders,
    {
      provide: CARD_PROVIDER_FACADE_FACTORY,
      useClass: serviceAFactory,
    },
```

implementation 2

```js
@Module({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [
    ...commonProviders,
    {
      provide: CARD_PROVIDER_FACADE_FACTORY,
      useClass: serviceBFactory,
    },
```

My issue occurring is whatever is initialised first overwrites the provider so if serviceBFactory initialises first then it injects service B to the other microservice that should of injected serviceAFactory

TLDR: When serviceA is called by our facade if serviceB is initialised last then serviceB's factory is injected. I assumed that by scoping each in their own thread would separate the scope. What am I missing here? Is their a clean solution?

Sorry if this is a little convoluted first stack overflow question

EDIT: As an update that I think fixed the issue. I imported each of the files lazily with the await import('') syntax. Because of this only the worker has access to his own imported service.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'new Worker' behaves slightly different than what you expect. It's a non-blocking instruction, so it means all three workers are created in one go in this.mainThread loop.

You can send some messages from the workers, when they are initialized as a promise (https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) and you can trigger new worker creations in a sequence(create a new one when the first one is created). But in this case you can not start all them at once.